# json stringify with variables

Tags: javascript, json

I am using JSON stringify, here is my code:

```
var lista={};
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        lista[i]=[];
        //lista[i].push('imagen:'+arr[i].id);
        lista[i].push('nick:'+arr[i].nick); 
        lista[i].push('tlfno:'+arr[i].tlfno);
        lista[i].push('nombre:'+arr[i].nombre);
        lista[i].push('descripcion:'+arr[i].descripcion);
        lista[i].push('direccion:'+arr[i].direccion);
        lista[i].push('fecha:'+arr[i].fecha);
        lista[i].push('estado:'+arr[i].estado);
        lista[i].push('tipoimagen:'+arr[i].tipoimagen);
        //lista[i].push('imagen:'+arr[i].imagen);
    }
    var json = JSON.stringify(lista);
    console.log(json);
```

I am getting this output:

```
{"0":["nick:pepe","tlfno:678909897","nombre:dsfdfsf","descripcion:dsdsdsd","direccion:fdfdf","fecha:fdfdf","estado:1","tipoimagen:image/jpeg"]
```

but is wrong because it would be like this:

`{"0":["nick":"pepe"` with double quotes, somebody knows how to show this double quote? Thanks

Comment: take a look here http://www.json.org/ ... so you might understand JSON better

Comment: haven't you what you want already in arr? Try out JSON.stringify(arr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to push objects into that array, not strings

```
lista[i].push( {nick: arr[i].nick} );
```

That would give you something like

```
{"0":[{"nick":"pepe"}]}
```

note that `{"0":["nick":"pepe"...` is not valid, so you won't be getting that

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2eSyj/1/)

Comment: adeneo hit it right on the head - in the line `lista[i].push('nick:'+arr[i].nick); `, you're pushing the string 'nick: pepe', instead of an object.